# PHP What is Static keyword

Tags: php, function, static

What is static keyword in function ?

**w3school**

> Normally, when a function is completed/executed, all of its variables
>   are deleted. However, sometimes we want a local variable NOT to be
>   deleted. We need it for a further job.

i don't undrstand , can anyone show me some code to undrstand it ?

Comment: See the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php - personally, I think W3School to be a rather poor source for learning programming, they do a lot of .. weird things at times.

Comment: Qirel thanks.
Yes, this is my point too. Is there Complete Source To Learn Php Language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static` has two different uses:

[**1. For classes:**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Make a method or a property accessible without needing an instantiation of the class.

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public static function aStaticMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}

Foo::aStaticMethod();
```

[**2. For functions:**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static)

A static variable exists only in a local function scope, but it does not lose its value when program execution leaves this scope.

```
<?php
function test()
{
    static $a = 0;
    echo $a;
    $a++;
}
test(); // 0
test(); // 1
test(); // 2
```

Without static:

```
<?php
function test()
{
    $a = 0;
    echo $a;
    $a++;
}
test(); // 0
test(); // 0
test(); // 0
```

It's a good practice to use it when you can, instead of filling the global scope with junk.